# Proof of the sum of the reciprocal non trivial zeros cubed

Tags: riemann-zeta-function

Just for fun I was trying to find a formula that calculates the value of the sum of the Riemann zeta non trivial roots raised to a power $n$, $Z(n)$.

$$Z(n) = \sum_{\rho} ' \frac{1}{\rho ^n}$$

I managed to find one monster of an equation after a while and it seems to work fine for $n=1$ but when I try $n=3$ the sum I have is almost exactly the same as the one given on Wolfram but with a negative sign on the $3\gamma \gamma_1 $ term.

According to the relation I derived there should be alternating signs in the gamma terms but Wolfram disagrees.
If it is needed I can type down my work, but basically I worked out that for $n>1$
$$
Z(n) = 1 - \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n} \zeta (n) + \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(-1)^{n-1-k} (k-1)!}{(n-1)!} B_{n,k} ((-1)^{n-k+1}(n-k+1)\gamma _{n-k}.
$$
For $n=1$ the equation it's slightly different but I have confirmed that case to be true.

Plugging in $n=3$ for this equation gives
$$
Z(3)=1+\frac{3}{2} \gamma _2 -3\gamma \gamma_1 +\gamma^3 - \frac{7}{8} \zeta (3)
$$
Wolfram gives the value
$$
Z(3)=1+\frac{3}{2} \gamma _2 +3\gamma \gamma_1 +\gamma^3 - \frac{7}{8} \zeta (3)
$$
instead. Can anybody prove the Wolfram version so at least I can try to find where I went wrong?

The $B_{n,k}$ are the Bell polynomials that I used in Faa di Bruno's formula to calculate $Z(n)$ and I shorthanded the notation slightly because it was too long.

Link to the page:

https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunctionZeros.html

Comment: (1) You use the notation $Z(n)$, but you never tell us what it means. (2) Somehow, when you plug in $n=3$, the left side remains $Z(n)$.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson my bad lemme edit it real quick.

Comment: OK. Now you can include the definition of $\gamma_i$.

Comment: The definition of the $\gamma_i$ can be found on the linked page.

Comment: @Gerry The numbers $\gamma_i$ are these https://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesConstants.html

Comment: @David, I figured as much, but it should be explicitly in the body of the question.

Comment: A closing parenthesis is missing in your long formula for $Z(n)$. Also, what's the meaning of the apostrophe on the first sum $\sum\limits_{\rho} '$?

Comment: You need to correct your formula for $Z(n)$. Assuming the first opening parenthesis following $B_{n,k}$ can be deleted, your formula doesn't match your result for $n=3$. Also note $(-1)^{n-k-1} (-1)^{n-k+1}=1$ so these two factors just drop out.

Comment: @Gerry I agree. I had to hunt for the link/definition as the page the OP linked to was not short. I will edit it in when I get time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This comes directly from the Hadamard product given in the Wolfram page you
refer to by taking logarithmic derivatives and identifying powers of $s$.
However, following Harold Stark, the classical formula given in Wolfram should
be replaced by the much simpler formula
$s(s-1)\Lambda(s)=\prod_{\rho}(1-s/\rho)$, where the product is to be
understood as the limit as $T\to\infty$ of $\prod_{|\Im(\rho)|<T}$, and
as usual $\Lambda(s)=\pi^{s/2}\Gamma(s/2)\zeta(s)$. Now take logarithmic
derivatives and the formula follows.

One can also easily obtain a recursion (equivalent to your use of Bell
polynomials): define by induction
$$\delta_{k+1}=(k+1)\dfrac{\gamma_k}{k!}+\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\dfrac{\gamma_j\delta_{k-j}}{j!}\quad\text{($\delta_1=\gamma_0=\gamma)$}\;.$$
Then $Z(k)=1-(1-1/2^k)\zeta(k)+\delta_k\;.$

Comment: You're right I'm stupid, didn't do the derivative properly.